# How do I use a custom Class to Return data from a web service

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-serialization, xsd

So I have an application that uses a webservice, On the UI side the user picks a table which sends a request across the web to my webservice to return the fields of this table.

So after this request is accomplished I have, on the webservice side a series of Name,Type Pairs that I need to serialize and send back to my client. I could use a List(of String()) to send the values back but I want to use a List(of Custom_Class) instead because later I have to do this on a much larger scale and I want to learn on this simpler version.

Now I know from my research that I can create a class from an .XSD document so what I'm thinking I should do is convert this class into a .XSD and somehow send that with my request to the WebService so that it can use that .XSD to create a class dynamically at runtime, instantiate that class into objects, fill those objects with the result set, bundle it into a strongly typed List(of ReturnFields), serialize that into XML, send it back to my client, Deserialize it back and display it for him.

So 2 questions:
1. Am I on the right track here or am I going about this all the wrong way.
2. How do I pass the .XSD schema to my Webservice so it can use it to create the class on the server side?

---

--------------EDIT-----------
So based on pMartin's input I'm revising this question a bit.

So below is my code as it stands now.

I have a "Fields" Class Living on my Library Layer

```
Public Class Fields
    Private Field_Name As String
    Private Field_Type As System.Type

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    End Sub

    Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return Field_Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Field_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Property Type() As System.Type
        Get
            Return Field_Type
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As System.Type)
            Field_Type = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

This get's used in my library by the following code.

```
Public Function Get_List_Of_Fields(ByVal Table_Name As String, ByVal Database_Name As String) As List(Of Fields)
    Dim List_Of_Fields As New List(Of Fields)
    Dim DataModel As MetaModel = Get_Datamodel(Database_Name)

    Dim Data_Table = (From DataTable In DataModel.GetTables Where DataTable.TableName = Table_Name).FirstOrDefault

    For Each Field In Data_Table.RowType.DataMembers
        Dim Fields_Obj As New Fields
        Fields_Obj.Name = Field.Name
        Fields_Obj.Type = Field.Type
        List_Of_Fields.Add(Fields_Obj)
    Next
    Return List_Of_Fields
End Function
```

Which Returns to my Webservice (.ASMX)

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function Get_List_of_Fields(ByVal Table_Name As String, ByVal Database_Name As String) As List(Of Fields)
    Return _DynaLib.Get_List_Of_Fields(Table_Name, Database_Name)
End Function
```

Which returns to my Client
'This is where my error is on this "return" line

```
Imports Dynamic_Charting.DynamicReference 
Private _DynamicService As New DynamicServiceSoapClient

Public Function Get_List_of_Fields(ByVal Table_name As String, ByVal Database_Name As String) As List(Of Fields)
     Return _DynamicService.Get_List_of_Fields(Table_name, Database_Name)
 End Function
```

It is here that I have my error. I get the following Error.

Error   11
Value of type '1-dimensional array of Dynamic_Charting.DynamicReference.Fields' cannot be converted to 
'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Dynamic_Charting.DynamicReference.Fields)'.

Comment: First, I would have put the EDIT in a new question. What you're asking now doesn't have any relation to the title or original intent of your question. I don't see anything wrong with your code, but I also don't see where you create a reference to the service on your client. Are you sure that `_DynamicService` is actually referencing the correct version of your web service? It looks to me like the compiler still thinks that `_DynamicService.Get_List_of_Fields` is returning a single `Fields` object.

Comment: Your right of course about the edit. I'll change my Title to reflect the Question being currently discussed.  I also added the code to my client snippit that shows how I'm referencing the Webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason that you need to pass an XML schema back and forth between the client and the web service. If you want to use a custom class to send back your output data, you can just set your custom class as the return type on the web service method.

Essentially, you would have a definition like this for your web service method (assuming that you  also have a class called InputFields to capture the data about the table that the user picked):

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function MyWebMethod(inputData As InputFields) As ReturnFields
    ...
End Function
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean that I have to build the class on both my Client side and my WebService side? Otherwise won't I get a "ReturnFields not defined" error in my webservice?

Comment: When you build the client, you should run wsdl.exe (.NET 2.0 Web Services) or svcutil.exe (WCF Web Services) against the web service's WSDL to generate the classes neccessary for the client to consume the web service.

Comment: So, and forgive the continuous questions I'm trying to really get a handle on this, I build the customer "return" class in the WebService project (I'm coding in Visual Studio 2008) and how do I set up my client to do what you said during it's build action?

Comment: I assume that you have one project which holds the web service code. I assume that you have one project which holds the client code. I also assume that the web service and client code live in a single solution. So, first you need to develop the web service code. Create the classes you need for input/output information and also for the web service method. Then, in your client project, choose "Add Web Reference" and select the Web Service project in your solution as the reference. This will add a the neccessary service and class references to your client.

Comment: Ok I think I'm getting a handle on this (you have been so tremendously helpful that it is unbelievable). My situation is as follows: I have 3 layers. My Client Layer (A vb.net windows form), A Webservice Layer (.ASMX), and a Library layer (.vb file) where the guts of my code for the webservice live. I place my "Fields" Class in my Library Layer and populated a "List(of Fields)" which I return to my Webservice layer. No problem there its working great. My Webservice see's the Fields class through it's reference to the Library and accepts the return collection. But there's an error going further

Comment: I build the Library and Webservice and update the Service Reference and get the following error on my Client form. -------------  Error 11 Value of type '1-dimensional array of Dynamic_Charting.DynamicReference.Fields' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Dynamic_Charting.DynamicReference.Fields)'. C:\ssoApplications\Dynamic Charting\Dynamic Charting\ServiceAccess.vb 440 16 Dynamic Charting

Comment: Updating the service reference will not update the client code. It only updates the references to the web service code. Without seeing the actual code, it sounds like your client code is trying to assign the web service response data to a variable of type `List<T>`. However, now that the web service is returning data in type `ReturnFields`, the client code that actually calls the service needs to be updated so that the variable being populated with the data returned by the web service call is of type `ReturnFields`

Comment: So I updated my question to include the relevant code. Thank you for all your help, I am so much closer now than I was before, please continue to allow me to learn from your knowledge on this issue by reviewing it and letting me know what you think.

Comment: Interesting note, if I change the Return of my Client Function to Field() the error goes away.

Comment: It sounds like somewhere along the line, your web service class reference was not updated correctly in your client project. You might try removing the reference to the web service in the client entirely, and then re-adding it.